# "Our generation" - it, they or we?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, pronouns, collective-nouns

My sentence is: "Our generation work (because "generation" is a collective noun and here I use it in the plural) mainly on computers, we/they/it do(es) not need...". Which pronoun should I use?

Comment: Generation is a collective noun. It takes a singular concord: *Our generation works...* That's generally true in American English *and* more common in British English, even though they have a few exceptions like "Government" that are generally used with plural concord.

Comment: You'd never use *they* instead of *we*, but pace user3...'s answer below *it* is also perfectly acceptable. *We* makes it more personal; *it* more impersonal. You'd use the latter if you were making a generally true point that you wanted to exempt yourself from.

Comment: @Ily 'Generation is a collective noun. It takes a singular concord  ... [this is] more common [than using plural concord] in British English, even though they have a few exceptions like "Government" that are generally used with plural concord.' That's not _my_ experience at all. Brits generally tend to use notional agreement, so 'The British Government underwent an important period of reform during the 19th century' but  'Mark Field MP responded by stating that the British government are deeply concerned about the situation'. Institution vs MPs.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "our generation", like any group including first person plural (our family, our team, etc.), can be substituted by the pronoun ***WE***.

Look at some examples from Reverso.context.net:

And then, like everyone else in our generation, ***we*** went to live in a Himalayan monastery.

In our generation, ***we*** cannot be expected to complete the monumental task which lies before ***us***, but neither are ***we*** at liberty to abstain from it.

Posterity will not spare its judgement on our generation if ***we*** do not rise to this challenge.

Comment: @Katabalista There is a problem that has not been addressed. *Generation* is singular. It should be *our generation* ***works***.